# Don't mess with Germans

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
3. High-pitched sound of loud automobile coming around too regularly (8)
7. Old TV show prosecutor's entertaining everyone (6)
9. Town in Arcadia orders one to retire (6)
10. Shake alien's spaceships (7)
11. Plan of wrestler and actor, John: Visiting small city in the tropics (8)
12. Align wheels to one in Munich (3,2)
14. Cross Mr. McKellen showing old capital (2'2)
15. I overlooked mix CD, produced 1410 (4)
19. Plays lead roles to get fixtures on Hollywood Walk of Fame (5)
20. A number of criminals controlling Frankfurt's #1 theme park (3,5)
22. Diana's only accepted Victor's break up (8)
24. Dictator's hunted innocent (6)
25. Berlin criminal ring kidnapped six (6)
26. Rabbits caught by boomerang or a spear (7)

**Down**
1. Space where things may be stored and gemstones flourish, according to Spooner (3-4)
2. Otherwise in Gelsenkirchen (4)
4. Part of France's tourists finally entered Schönbrunn, perhaps needing no introduction (6)
5. Increasingly threadlike small layer covering piece of jewellery (9)
6. Set up, turn about, making intitial attempt (4,3)
7. Fish can can, maybe, can bottom of can (4)
8. Article on American metal producer, wrestler and actor, Steve (6)
13. Oops! Ladle spilt sauce (3,2,4)
15. Ex dancing with manic latino? (7)
16. Mountaineer's stirrup from German city south of a border of France (6)
17. Germanic kingdom of different sexes (5)
18. Christie is good at being in band (6)
21. Horse-fly's appendage is under cat-person's head (4)
23. Prison I initially recognised south of Stuttgart on vacation (4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Grid:

> [image]

**Across**

> 3. FALSETTO **F TESLA< T(-o)O** High-pitched sound of loud automobile coming around too regularly (8)
>  7. DALLAS **DA'S entertaining ALL** Old TV show prosecutor's entertaining everyone (6)
>  9. ASTROS **(SORTS A)<** Town in Arcadia orders one to retire (6)
>  10. ROCKETS **ROCK ET'S** Shake alien's spaceships (7)
>  11. SCENARIO **CENAR visiting S RIO** Plan of wrestler and actor, John: Visiting small city in the tropics (8)
>  12. TOE IN **TO + EIN** Align wheels to one in Munich (3,2)
>  14. XI'AN **X + IAN** Cross Mr. McKellen showing old capital (2'2)
>  15. MCDX **(M(-i)XCD)*** I overlooked mix CD, produced 1410 (4)
>  19. STARS **ddef** Plays lead roles to get fixtures on Hollywood Walk of Fame (5)
>  20. SIX FLAGS **SIX LAGS around F(-rankfurt)** A number of criminals controlling Frankfurt's #1 theme park (3,5)
>  22. DISSOLVE **DI'S SOLE accepting V** Diana's only accepted Victor's break up (8)
>  24. CHASTE **homophone of CHASED** Dictator's hunted innocent (6)
>  25. IRVING **RING* kidnapping VI** Berlin criminal ring kidnapped six (6)
>  26. ANGORAS **substring** Rabbits caught by boomerang or a spear (7)

**Down**

> 1. BOX-ROOM **spoonerism of ROCKS BOOM** Space where things may be stored and gemstones flourish, according to Spooner (3-4)
>  2. ELSE **substring** Otherwise in Gelsenkirchen (4)
>  4. ALSACE **(-tourist)S in (-p)ALACE** Part of France's tourists finally entered Schönbrunn, perhaps needing no introduction (6)
>  5. STRINGIER **S TIER covering RING** Increasingly threadlike small layer covering piece of jewellery (9)
>  6. TEST RUN **SET< + TURN*** Set up, turn about, making intitial attempt (4,3)
>  7. DACE **DANCE, canning (i.e., discarding) (-ca)N** Fish can can, maybe, can bottom of can (4)
>  8. AUSTIN **A US TIN** Article on American metal producer, wrestler and actor, Steve (6)
>  13. OLD EL PASO **(OOPS LADLE)*** Oops! Ladle spilt sauce (3,2,4)
>  15. MEXICAN **(EX MANIC)*** Ex dancing with manic latino? (7)
>  16. ETRIER **TRIER south of (-franc)E** Mountaineer's stirrup from German city south of a border of France (6)
>  17. ESSEX **SEXES*** Germanic kingdom of different sexes (5)
>  18. AGATHA **G AT in A-HA** Christie is good at being in band (6)
>  21. CLEG **LEG under C(-atperson)** Horse-fly's appendage is under cat-person's head (4)
>  23. STIR **I R(-ecognised) south of S(-tuttgar)T** Prison I initially recognised south of Stuttgart on vacation (4)

Incidentally, I (entirely unreasonably) don't like 18d because

> etymologically AGATHA actually means "good" :-).

More seriously,

> aren't the two defs in 19a rather closely related to one another? I suspect the HWOF uses stars exactly *because* (acting) stars are called stars, but if not then I bet it uses stars for the same reason as why (acting) stars are called stars, i.e., because the brightness of actual stars symbolizes the impressiveness of the actors.

Theme explanation (addition from OP):

> As mentioned in the comments, the theme here was the state of Texas. **Dallas**, **Irving** and **Austin** are all cities in the state, and the **Astros**, the **Rockets** and the **Stars** are all Texas-based pro sports teams. In addition there's the Texas-based theme park corporation **Six Flags** and the food brand **Old El Paso** which references another major city in the state. The title references the state's slogan "Don't mess with Texas".
>
>  There's also a pointer to the theme of the puzzle hidden in the grid:
>
>  [image]

Comment: Jeremy posted his all-but-one-and-no-grid-yet answer 9 minutes before my complete answer. Of course I haven't looked at his. Jafe, feel free to make whatever judgement you please about priority :-).

Comment: I should add that 9 minutes ago I was missing _two_ answers. (But had been filling in the grid as I went.)

Comment: Great catch on 7D. No worries about sharing meaningless Internet points :-)

Comment: "Catch", ho ho. That was actually my _second_-last one; 7a was my last. I'm not great at popular culture, though I had at least heard of the show in question.

Comment: I'm old enough that 7a was my first! I'm great on pop culture...from 30 years ago. Not sure if intentional on jafe's part, but I seem to remember that show was very big in Germany back in the day.

Comment: Oh, I'm also _old_ enough to remember the show. But e.g. I never watched it.

Comment: Agreed on 19a, not a great choice of definitions in retrospect.

Comment: @JeremyDover Not intentional and I wasn't aware it was popular there. But of course the real theme isn't Germany here ;)

Comment: I completely missed the real theme while solving, but there does seem to be a lot of rot13(Grknf) in the answers.

Answer (score 7):

**COMPLETED GRID**

> [image: Completed grid]

**ACROSS**

> 3. FALSETTO = F (forte/loud) + TESLA< + ToO
>  7. DALLAS = DA'S + ALL
>  9. [ASTROS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astros,_Greece) = A + SORTS<
>  10. ROCKETS = ROCK + ET'S
>  11. SCENARIO = S (small) + CENA + RIO
>  12. [TOE IN](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toe-in) = TO + EIN
>  14. [XI'AN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xi%27an) = X (cross) + IAN
>  15. MCDX = M(-i)X + CD
>  19. STARS (ddef.)
>  20. SIX FLAGS = SIX + [LAGS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lag) (British slang) + F_
>  22. DISSOLVE = DI'S + SOLE + V (phonetic)
>  24. CHASTE = "CHASED"
>  25. IRVING = RING* + VI
>  26. ANGORAS = _ANG OR A S_

**DOWN**

> 1. [BOX-ROOM](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/box%20room) = "ROCKS BOOM" (Spooner)
>  2. ELSE = gELSEenkirchen
>  4. ALSACE = (-p)ALACE + _S
>  5. STRINGIER = S (small) + TIER + RING
>  6. TEST RUN = SET< + TURN*
>  7. DACE = ????
>  8. [AUSTIN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjWPoQWdmjg) = A + US + TIN
>  13. [OLD EL PASO](https://www.oldelpaso.com/products/mild-taco-sauce-9-oz) = OOPS LADLE*
>  15. MEXICAN = EX + MANIC*
>  16. ETRIER = _E + TRIER
>  17. ESSEX = SEXES*
>  18. AGATHA = A-HA + G_ + AT
>  21. [CLEG](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cleg) = C_ + LEG
>  23. STIR = I + R_ south of S_T (Stuttgart, on vacation...nice, jafe!!!!)